# How to get the program to delete an element from the class

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning C++ and can't figure out how to get the program to delete an item from the item list once the quantity becomes 0.

```
class Item {
private:
    std::string name;
    int quantity;
    float price;

public:
    Item(
            std::string name,
            int quantity,
            float price
    ) :
            name{std::move(name)},
            quantity{quantity},
            price{price} {

    }

    std::string get_name() const {
        return name;
    }

    int get_quantity() const {
        return quantity;
    }

    void set_quantity(int new_quantity) {
        quantity = new_quantity;
    }

    float get_price() const {
        return price;
    }

    bool is_match(const std::string &other) {
        return name == other;
    }
};

class Inventory {
private:
    Item *items[20];
    float total_money;
    int item_count;

    static void display_data(Item &item) {
        std::cout << "\nItem name: " << item.get_name();
        std::cout << "\nQuantity: " << item.get_quantity();
        std::cout << "\nPrice: " << item.get_price();
    }

public:
    Inventory() :
            items{},
            total_money{0},
            item_count{0} {

    }

    void sell_item() {
        std::string item_to_check;
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "\nEnter item name: ";
        std::cin >> item_to_check;

        for (int i = 0; i < item_count; i++) {
            if (items[i]->is_match(item_to_check)) {
                remove_item(i);
                return;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\nThis item is not in your Inventory";
    }

    void remove_item(int item_index) {
        int input_quantity;
        Item *item = items[item_index];
        std::cout << "\nEnter number of items to sell: ";
        std::cin >> input_quantity;

        int quantity = item->get_quantity();
        if (input_quantity <= quantity) {
            float price = item->get_price();
            float money_earned = price * input_quantity;
            item->set_quantity(quantity - input_quantity);
            std::cout << "\nItems sold";
            std::cout << "\nMoney received: " << money_earned;
            total_money += money_earned;
        } else {
            std::cout << "\nCannot sell more items than you have.";
        }
    }
};
```

I tried using basic methods from sites like javatpoint like using a loop to remove the element, but it won't work. Any suggestions on how i can remove the elements?

Comment: `Item *items[20];` --> `std::vector<Item> items;`.  Then a simple `items.erase(items.begin() + item_index);` removes the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove an element from a fixed array.  But, what you can do is move the values of subsequent elements down a slot in the array, and then decrement your `item_count`, eg:

```
void remove_item(int item_index) {
    int input_quantity;
    Item *item = items[item_index];
    std::cout << "\nEnter number of items to sell: ";
    std::cin >> input_quantity;

    int quantity = item->get_quantity();
    if (input_quantity <= quantity) {
        ...
        item->set_quantity(quantity - input_quantity);
        ...
        if (item->get_quantity() <= 0) {
            delete item; // <-- assuming your Items are created with 'new'...
            for(int i = item_index + 1; i < item_count; ++i) {
                Items[i-1] = Items[i];
            }
            --item_count;
            Items[item_count] = nullptr;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "\nCannot sell more items than you have.";
    }
}
```

That being said, you really should be using `std::vector` instead of a fixed array, eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

...

class Inventory {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items;
    // don't need item_count anymore!
    ...

    ...

public:
    ...

    void sell_item() {
        ...

        for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
            if (items[i]->is_match(item_to_check)) {
                remove_item(i);
                return;
            }
        }

        ...
    }

    void remove_item(size_t item_index) {
        int input_quantity;
        auto &item = items[item_index];
        std::cout << "\nEnter number of items to sell: ";
        std::cin >> input_quantity;

        int quantity = item->get_quantity();
        if (input_quantity <= quantity) {
            ...
            item->set_quantity(quantity - input_quantity);
            ...
            if (item->get_quantity() <= 0)
                items.erase(items.begin() + item_index);
        } else {
            std::cout << "\nCannot sell more items than you have.";
        }
    }

    void add_item() {
        ...
        items.push_back(std::make_unique<Item>(name, quantity, price));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks your code works. but when i tried adding the vector, it clashed with this part of the code. What can i do to fix the error? It says no viable overloader when i try
`void add_item() {
        std::string name;
        int quantity;
        float price;

        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "\nEnter item name: ";
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout << "Enter quantity: ";
        std::cin >> quantity;
        std::cout << "Enter price: ";
        std::cin >> price;

        items[item_count] = new Item(name, quantity, price);
        item_count++;
    } `

Comment: @Ironavenger475 `std::vector` holds a dynamic array. Use it's `push_back()` method to add items to it. I have updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop and array shifting after freeing the item from the memory. Since the array is static this is the only way. All elements need to be shifted once slot back after removing the concerned item.

```
void remove_item(int item_index)
{
    int input_quantity;
    Item *item = items[item_index];
    cout << "\nEnter number of items to sell: ";
    cin >> input_quantity;

    int quantity = item->get_quantity();
    if (input_quantity <= quantity)
    {
        float price = item->get_price();
        float money_earned = price * input_quantity;
        item->set_quantity(quantity - input_quantity);
        cout << "\nItems sold";
        cout << "\nMoney received: " << money_earned;
        total_money += money_earned;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nCannot sell more items than you have.";
    }
    if (item->get_quantity() == 0)
    {
        removeItemFromList(item);
    }
}

// remove item from list once quantity is 0
void removeItemFromList(Item *item)
{
    delete item;
    for (int i = 0; i < item_count; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] == item)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < item_count - 1; j++)
            {
                items[j] = items[j + 1];
            }
            item_count--;
            break;
        }
    }
    item = nullptr;
}
```